# bash: How to extract any dirname from the path

Tags: bash, shell

So, I have a few basename such as

`./home/mnt/users/upload/random/reports/on/a/server.md`
`./home/mnt/users/upload2/random/reports/on/a/server.md`
`./home/mnt/users/upload3/random/reports/on/a/server.md`

I want to extract the dirname (look for THIS) after the `.../users/**THIS**/random/....`
so the output should be either upload, upload2 or upload3

tried with few options such as

```
file=./home/mnt/users/upload/random/reports/on/a/server.md
echo ${file%/*}
echo $(basename $(dirname $(dirname $file)))
```

how can I achieve that?

Comment: please update the question with the expected output

Comment: cut-n-paste your script, along with appropriate shebang, into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and make the suggested changes

Comment: updated, hopefully makes sense now ?

Comment: You still didn't clarify what the expected output is.

Comment: Try `IFS=/; set $file; echo "$5"` after you get `$file` set.

Comment: please update the question with a couple different examples that demonstrate *`dir name is not fixed at this level`*; also update the question to show the expected output for each input

Comment: @ColeTierney, that's going to misbehave with some names. If the user's path includes a directory named `*`, for example, `set $file` is _really_ going to have surprising behaviors.

Comment: To guess at a few things you might want and ask whether they're correct... Do you want to take the path component immediately after `./home/mnt/users`, whatever that is? Take the path component 5 levels from the name, whatever that is? Take the component 5 levels from the root, whatever that is? Don't make us guess what the behavior you're trying to implement is; describe in English text how the code should know that "uploads" is the level you want, and show enough examples to rule out things that might reach "uploads" with this name but do the wrong thing with others.

Comment: not sure why some people are not able to understand. Apologies I have made this a bit more clearer

Comment: Try `awk -F/ '{print $5}' <<< "$file"` if you don't like running with scissors :)

Comment: Or spice it up to find the part between `users` and `random` regardless of the order, e.g. `awk -F"/" '{for(i=1;i<=NF-2;i++) { if ($i == "users" && $(i+2) == "random") print $(i+1)}}' <<< "$file"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `sed` approach to extract the name of the directory that has parent and child directories of `/users/` and `/random/`, respectively:

```
sed -En 's:.*/users/([^/]+)/random/.*:\1:p'
```

Where:

- `-E` - enable extended regex support (and capture groups)
- `-n` - suppress default printing of pattern space
- `.*/users/` - match on leading regex `.*/users/`
- `([^/]+)` - (capture group #1) - match on anything not a `/`
- `/random/.*` - match on trailing regex `/random/.*`
- `\1:p` - print contents of capture group #1

Taking for a test drive:

```
for fname in './home/mnt/users/upload/random/reports/on/a/server.md' './home/mnt/users/upload2/random/reports/on/a/server.md' './home/mnt/users/upload3/random/reports/on/a/server.md'
do
    echo "############ $fname"
    sed -En 's:.*/users/([^/]+)/random/.*:\1:p' <<< "${fname}"
done
```

This generates:

```
############ ./home/mnt/users/upload/random/reports/on/a/server.md
upload
############ ./home/mnt/users/upload2/random/reports/on/a/server.md
upload2
############ ./home/mnt/users/upload3/random/reports/on/a/server.md
upload3
```

Answer (score 0):

With `bash`'s regular expression operator (`=~`):

```
[[ $pathname =~ /users/([^/]*) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```